# Task{} works but .task{} throws Invalid conversion from throwing function of type error?

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await

I am trying to understand the reason behind why does `Task{}`  works but when I do it with the `VStack{}.task{}` I am getting the error:

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '@Sendable () async
> throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '@Sendable () async ->
> Void'

I am trying to have the `fetchWeather()` function run the moment the view starts without having the user to tap on the button. (If the below way is the correct way to do so) but ran upon this error and am really curious to the reasoning behind this error

Below is my code:

```
struct WeatherView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
           Text("Hello, World!")
           Button("Get Weather", action: {
            // Works when I tap the button
//                Task {
//                    try await fetchWeather()
//                }
        })
    }
    //*******Xcode error with invalid conversion*******
    .task {
        try await fetchWeather()
    }
  }
}

struct WeatherView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
       WeatherView( )
   }
}
```

The function:

```
func fetchWeather () async throws  {
   let URLString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=someAPIKeyshere&q=seattle"
   let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from:  URL(string: URLString)!)
   guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
      httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
          throw ResponseError.someError
      }
   let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherData.self, from: data)
   print("This is in decodedResponse: \(decodedResponse)")
}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand, but I would avoid `try?` on the decoding. You’re in a function that can throw errors, so just go ahead and `try` the decoding, so that if it failed, you know why. Right now you are potentially throwing away useful diagnostic information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the error message you're getting…

Your function is of type:

```
@Sendable () async throws -> ()
```

whereas the `.task` modifier is expecting…

```
@Sendable () async -> Void
```

The difference is the `throws`.

To resolve this, you need to handle errors thrown by your function, e.g.…

```
.task {
    do {
        try await fetchWeather()
    } catch {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

You can compare the parameters that the initialiser for `Task` and the `.task` modifier take:

**`Task.init`**

```
init(priority: TaskPriority? = nil, operation: @escaping @Sendable () async throws -> Success)
```

**`.task` modifier**

```
func task(priority: TaskPriority = .userInitiated, _ action: @escaping @Sendable () async -> Void) -> some View
```

Answer (score 2):

That´s a known behaviour of `Task{}`. It hides errors in its result and can have unhandeled `throwing` functions. The `.task` modifier does not. If you want to use `throwing` functions inside it you need to handle them with a `do/catch` block.

```
.task {
    do{
        try await fetchWeather()
    } catch{
    }
}
```

You can [read](https://forums.swift.org/t/task-initializer-with-throwing-closure-swallows-error/56066) on swift forum about that issue.

Comment: I understand what you’re trying to say, but I would hesitate to suggest that `Task` “hides” the error. `Task` actually captures the error (and if you save the resulting `Task<Success, Failure>` object, you can `try await` its `value`). It’s just that the OP was discarding the error handled by `Task`. But, it is a distinction without merit, because the `.task {…}` pattern is preferrable (as it is structured concurrency and automatically handles cancelation if the view is dismissed), but we might not want to leave readers with the idea that errors are “hidden” by `Task`.